# How do I validate if a django URLfield is from a specific domain or hostname?

Tags: django, validation, model

Hi I want to see if a models.URLfield is from youtube or soundcloud.

```
url = models.URLField("URL", max_length=255, unique = True)
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a validator method, which parses the url and checks the hostname, and add this to your field.

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from django.db import models
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


def validate_url(value):
    if not value:
        return  # Required error is done the field
    obj = urlparse(value)
    if not obj.hostname in ('youtube.com', 'soundcloud.com'):
        raise ValidationError('Only urls from YouTube or SoundCloud allowed')


class ModelA(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField(
        verbose_name="URL", max_length=255, unique=True, validators=[validate_url]
    )
```

Edited example; a validator shouldn't return a value. It's not like a clean method on a form.

See more info at:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/validators/

Comment: Check the urllib documentation. It also has values like netloc, which contains the www, and scheme. Thus you could expand the if-statement (as example) with `and obj.scheme == 'https'`